# Dynamic if question - in logical value becomes dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a dynamic if statement, not sure if it is possible in excel. What I want to perform is, there are 2 columns, A and B, I want to check if the value of corresponding A's cell has the value "Yes", then in the corresponding cell of B, there is a fixed value. If in case, A# doesn't have "Yes", but a "No", in that case, I want the user to fill in the value in the particular B#.

I have already tried using conditional formatting with colors, but what I want is if the condition is met, a fixed value comes. In all other cases, I want user to put in dynamic.

A1 cell has value = "Yes", B1 becomes "good"
A2 cell has value = "No", B2 asks the user to fill in the value

Comment: You can change a cells value with a formula, but you can't leave it truly blank for the user to fill in a value, as the formula will be in the cell and will have to be manually replaced. It can be done with VBA though if that's an option for you.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the same. Either way, I guess my best option is to use conditional formatting then.